# Do something on third party AJAX load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that appends links to each product in a product list which I can do on initial page load, however the page pagination works via ajax. So when someone clicks to view the next page, it doesn't fire.

I've tried using ajaxComplete() but because the link that I append does some ajax stuff, it fires again once that's clicked, causing multiple links to be appended. Is it not possible to have ajaxComplete() fire only when the new products are loaded and not when my appended links are clicked?

I would like to fire the function which adds the links after the ajax is completed, but I don't have access to that ajax script so I can't add it in as part of that script.

Cheers.

Comment: The question is a little vague to be easily answered. Are you able to provide sample code, maybe a jsfiddle? Does your pagination function return the jqXHR function, so you could add a done/always handler to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the url of ajax request in ajaxComplete like this:-

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,xhr,settings){
   if(settings.url=='google.com')
    {
          // do something here 
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y6XgY/375/)

Comment: Brilliant, easy as that :) Thanks!